# Is there a way to update the Editor column on SharePoint from an Azure function that uploads documents?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, azure-functions

I'm struggling to find a way to update the "Editor (Modified By)" column on a SharePoint library when I upload documents on it with an Azure Function.

It seems like that the value always gets overridden by the user "SharePoint APP", which also make sense because is a SharePoint application that is uploading the files.

For business specs I need to override that value with a user that comes from a JSON pushed to the function. I'm only able to do so on custom columns but not on the "Editor" or "Author" column.

I've tried this code here:

```
private static void upload(FileCreationInformation file, string folderPath, ClientContext ctx, string type, string displayName, string contractManagerEmail)

{

    Folder library = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath);

    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadfile = library.Files.Add(file);

    ListItem metadata = uploadfile.ListItemAllFields;

    FieldUserValue contractManagerUserValue = FieldUserValue.FromUser(contractManagerEmail);

//THIS IS A CUSTOM COLUMN    
metadata["Modifiedby"] = contractManagerUserValue;

    metadata.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

    ctx.Load(uploadfile);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    ListItem newMeta = uploadfile.ListItemAllFields;

    //FieldUserValue value = FieldUserValue.FromUser(contractManagerEmail);

    var user = ctx.Web.EnsureUser(contractManagerEmail);

    newMeta["Editor"] = user;

    newMeta["Author"] = user;

    newMeta.Update();

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

}
```

I'm using these libraries to connect with SharePoint:

#r "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

#r "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

#r "PnP.Framework.dll"

Comment: It is not possible to update the "Editor" or "Author" column on SharePoint with an Azure Function. These columns are system columns that are automatically updated by SharePoint when a user interacts with the document library.

Comment: it is just a thing that is unachievable by azure functions? or there is some way, without of course manual uploading of the files, to update those columns?

Comment: It would certainly be help if this would identify WHICH SharePoint App.  You might think this was an app credential config/property, but I have not been able to find any help in Azure Entra AD (formerly known as AD.)